# Rails db:migrate can't find gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rake

I'm trying to run the `rake db:migrate` command, but when I run it it tells me there is not a gem installed. I'll run `bundle install` and it'll execute correctly, but then It'll once again tell me that a gem is not installed. The gem it's telling me is not installed is the `minitest-5.8.0`.

This is what shows up after I do `bundle install`

```
Using rake 10.4.2
Using ZenTest 4.11.0
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.3
Using minitest 5.8.0
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using activesupport 4.2.1
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile 0.6.2
Using nokogiri 1.6.6.2
Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.6
Using loofah 2.0.2
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.2
Using actionview 4.2.1
Using rack 1.6.4
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using actionpack 4.2.1
Using globalid 0.3.6
Using activejob 4.2.1
Using mime-types 2.6.1
Using mail 2.6.3
Using actionmailer 4.2.1
Using activemodel 4.2.1
Using arel 6.0.3
Using activerecord 4.2.1
Using autotest 4.4.6
Using debug_inspector 0.0.2
Using binding_of_caller 0.7.2
Using columnize 0.9.0
Using byebug 5.0.0
Using coffee-script-source 1.9.1.1
Using execjs 2.5.2
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 4.2.1
Using coffee-rails 4.1.0
Using diff-lcs 1.2.5
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using haml 4.0.6
Using multi_json 1.11.2
Using jbuilder 2.3.1
Using jquery-rails 4.0.4
Using bundler 1.7.12
Using sprockets 3.2.0
Using sprockets-rails 2.3.2
Using rails 4.2.1
Using rdoc 4.2.0
Using rspec-support 3.3.0
Using rspec-core 3.3.2
Using rspec-expectations 3.3.1
Using rspec-mocks 3.3.2
Using rspec-rails 3.3.3
Using sass 3.4.16
Using sass-rails 5.0.3
Using sdoc 0.4.1
Using spring 1.3.6
Using sqlite3 1.3.10
Using turbolinks 2.5.3
Using uglifier 2.7.1
Using web-console 2.2.1
Your bundle is complete!
Gems in the group production were not installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

When I run `which ruby` It'll show me the path `/usr/local/bin/ruby` and when I run `bundle show minitest` it'll show me `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/minitest-5.8.0`

Why is it not detecting that minitest is installed.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `rake db:migrate` with `bundle exec`.

Your complete run command should be `bundle exec rake db:migrate`.

Comment: it gives me a segmentation fault in a json library

Answer (score 0):

I would try reinstall your ruby

```
rvm get stable
rvm reinstall ruby-2.3.0
```